# How do you pass a generated PDF to an API as an IO stream without writing it to disk?

Tags: python, pdf, io, cloudinary

I am using PyPDF2 to generate a PDF, and I would like to upload this PDF to [Cloudinary](http://cloudinary.com/documentation/), which accepts images as IO objects.

The example from their docs: `cloudinary.uploader.upload(open('/tmp/image1.jpg', 'rb'))`

In my application, I instantiate a PdfFileWriter and add pages:

```
output = PyPDF2.PdfFileWriter()
output.addPage(page)
```

Then I can save the generated PDF locally:

```
outputStream = file(destination_file_name, "wb")
output.write(outputStream)
outputStream.close()
```

But obviously I'm trying to avoid this. Instead I'm trying to send an IO object to cloudinary:

```
image_StringIO_object = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(image_StringIO_object)
cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_StringIO_object,
                           api_key=CLOUDINARY_API_KEY,
                           api_secret=CLOUDINARY_API_SECRET,
                           cloud_name=CLOUDINARY_CLOUD_NAME,
                           format="PDF")
```

This returns the error:

```
Empty file
```

If instead I try to pass the value of the StringIO object:

```
cloudinary.uploader.upload(image_StringIO_object.getvalue(),
                           ...)
```

I get the error:

```
file() argument 1 must be encoded string without null bytes, not str
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer from Cloudinary support:

The result from getvalue() on the StringIO object needs to be base64 encoded and prepended with a tag:

```
out = StringIO.StringIO()
output.write(out)
cloudinary.uploader.upload("data:image/pdf;base64," + 
                           base64.b64encode(out.getvalue()))
```